# Tkinter, как очищать поле после каждого нажатия

Tags: python, tkinter

Здравствуйте, написал код который после каждого нажатия кнопки рандомно выводит одно имя, но я заметил что после каждого нажатия остается часть текста предыдущего имени.
Вот скриншот: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA8F4.png
И я хочу спросить, можно ли после каждого нажатия кнопки сделать так чтобы поле очищалось?
Вот часть кода:

```
class Mirino(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(mGui)
        self.init_child()

    def mirino2(self):
        tk.Label(self, text='' + random.choice(code_list5)).place(x = 87, y = 110)
        return

    def init_child(self):
        self.title('Mirino')
        self.geometry('200x200')
        tk.Button(self, text='Mirino', command=self.mirino2).pack()
```

Comment: http://dropmefiles.com/8nM6w Загрузил файл на файлообменник потому что код очень долгий

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При помощи атрибута `config` можно обновлять текст. У вас в вашем коде при каждом нажатии на кнопку вызывается атрибут `tk.Label` и он накладывается друг на друга, по этому вам следует создать данный атрибут вместе с `button` после чего при помощи `config` обновлять текст

```
class Mirino(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.init_child()

    def mirino2(self):
        self.label_text.config(text=''+random.choice(code_list5))
        return

    def init_child(self):
        self.title('Mirino')
        self.geometry('200x200')
        self.label_text = tk.Label(self, text='' + random.choice(code_list5))
        self.label_text.place(x=87, y=110)
        tk.Button(self, text='Mirino', command=self.mirino2).pack()
```